# end of while loop is very buggy. displaying the incorrect iteration

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t program_time;
    time(&program_time);   //Time variable displays time

    string name;    //name variable, displays the name enter into cin

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    cout << "This is a C++ version of the Euclidean algorithm\n";
    cout << "it is named after the Greek mathematician Euclid.\n";
    cout << "What is your first name?\n";

    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello "<< name <<", Please enter two numbers.\n";
    cout << "Entry (1): "<< endl;

    cin >> a;

    cout << "You entered: " << a << endl;
    cout << "Entry (2): " << endl;

    cin >> b;

    cout << "You entered: " << b << endl;

    if(a < b) { //swaps entries
       c = a;
       a = b;
       b = c;
    }

    while(a != b) {//control
        int z = a;
        do {
            if(a != 1 && (!(a < b))) {
                cout << "\n" << a << " minus "; //displays calculation
            }
            if(a < b) {
                b -= a;
            } else {
                a -= b;
            }
            if(a != 1 && (!(a < b))) {
                cout << b << " equals:\n" << "   " << a << endl;  //displays result of each calculation
            }
        } while(a < b);
        if(a == 1) {
            cout << "   " << a << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n" << name << ", this is the greatest common divisor: " << a << endl;
    cout << "\nWould you like to know the time?(yes/no) if not, this program is complete (case sensitive).\t";
    string yes = "yes";

    cin >> yes;

    if(yes == "yes") {
        cout << ctime(&program_time) << endl;  //displays time
        cout << "Good Bye!";
    } else {
        cout << "Good Bye!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I input 234 and 23 then this is what the final output displays:

```
50 minus 23 equals:
   27

27 minus 3 equals:
   4

4 minus    1

stackoverflow, this is the greatest common divisor: 1
```

I cannot figure it out and I have been at it for a couple of hours.

I need to include the calculation and result of each iteration. If there is a simpler way to do this I would appreciate it and change it but I hope there is some suggestions that would not drastically alter my program

Comment: What can't you figure out? What did you expect to be the output of the program instead? Have you considered using some debugging techniques to find the problem?

Comment: 23 is a prime number and does not divide into 234 so there is no GCD.  1 is the only number that will divide into both.

Comment: If you are allergic to debuggers, you can always add `cout` statements to print out variable names and values.  Move these around or add a bunch.  If you write them to a file with a time stamp, you have created a logging system, that will show you a history of how your program operates.

Comment: does anyone know of a good online debugger?

Comment: You could take a look at https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Answer (score 1):

You're making this far more complicated than you need to. Euclid's algorithm is all about subtractions, and flipping order when the result would be otherwise-negative. A *very* stripped down version of this is demonstrated below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, b;
    if (std::cin >> a >> b && a > 0 && b > 0)
    {
        while (a != b && a > 1 && b > 1)
        {
            if (b < a)
            {
                std::cout << a << " - " << b << " = ";
                a -= b;
                std::cout << a << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << b << " - " << a << " = ";
                b -= a;
                std::cout << b << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Ans: " << a << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A few things. We read unsigned integers (so.. no negative inputs). Second, don't bother detecting the greater of the two before the loop; it doesn't matter. The code already accounts for that by reversing the arguments of the subtraction. In fact, that's the pointer of the algorithm. A sample run with your input test values of 234 23:

**Sample** (first line is input)

```
234
23
234 - 23 = 211
211 - 23 = 188
188 - 23 = 165
165 - 23 = 142
142 - 23 = 119
119 - 23 = 96
96 - 23 = 73
73 - 23 = 50
50 - 23 = 27
27 - 23 = 4
23 - 4 = 19
19 - 4 = 15
15 - 4 = 11
11 - 4 = 7
7 - 4 = 3
4 - 3 = 1
```

---

**Reference Alternative**

You can compact this further by initializing two references to `a` and `b`, the larger being bound to the `lhs` reference, the smaller to the `rhs` reference. Pictorially it makes sense, and has the bonus of reducing the code to just one subtract-and-report section:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, b;
    if (std::cin >> a >> b && a > 0 && b > 0)
    {
        while (a != b && a > 1 && b > 1)
        {
            unsigned int &lhs = (a < b) ? b : a;
            unsigned int &rhs = (a < b) ? a : b;

            std::cout << lhs << " - " << rhs << " = ";
            lhs -= rhs;
            std::cout << lhs << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "Ans: " << a << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in regards of the buggy display of information, the following code is wrong since you are decreasing values and then doing the same check as above. At some point (when b is greater than a), you will start skipping the 'cout << b  << " equals...' part, until a is greater than b again.

```
if(a != 1 && (!(a < b))) {
            cout << "\n" << a << " minus "; //displays calculation
        }
        if(a < b) {
            b -= a;
        } else {
            a -= b;
        }
        if(a != 1 && (!(a < b))) {
            cout << b << " equals:\n" << "   " << a << endl;  //displays result of each calculation
        }
```

Here is a little solution to that

```
if(a != 1 && (!(a < b))) {
            cout << "\n" << a << " minus " << b << " equals:\n" << "   " << a-b << endl;; //displays calculation
        }
        else
        if(a != 1 && (a < b))
        {
          cout << "\n" << b << " minus " << a << " equals:\n" << "   " << b-a << endl;; //displays calculation
        }
        if(a < b) {
            b -= a;
        } else {
            a -= b;
        }
```

Comment: I changed the ending of the loop to the loop around before seeing this but thank you for the support!